# RSpec-rails. The rendered method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

The `rendered` method in RSpec-rails' views examples is used for getting a rendered view template.

For example:

```
describe 'example/show.html.haml' do
  it 'displays \'ok!\'' do
    render
    rendered.should have_content('ok!')
  end
end
```

I'm in a difficulty in finding this method's roots. Where does it come from?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1;

Ruby 1.9.2;

Ruby on Rails 3.1.0.rc4;

RSpec-rails 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an `attr_accessor` for the `@rendered` instance variable, which is set by the `render` method in `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior`. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/test_case.rb#L108-112.